# Error installing React Native: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/yallist failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:443

Tags: react-native

I am installing React Native by running the following command:

```
sudo npm install -g create-react-native-app
```

but I am getting the following error:

```
npm ERR! code EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! errno EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/yallist failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:443

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/zeusx/.npm/_logs/2017-08-16T05_07_19_737Z-debug.log
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: are you installing react-native using proxy network ?

Answer (score 0):

Install react native cli using

`npm install -g react-native-cli`

Then create project using

`react-native init "ProjectName"`

run using `react-native run-android` or `react-native run-ios`